# Prevent the user from changing their e-mail aliases

Tags: email, mail-server, aliases

Does anyone know how the "Citadel e-mail server" prevents the user can define their e-mail aliases yourself?

I've already read the FAQ, but unfortunately I have not found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my current version (8.17) only users with Aide rights can change their e-mail alias on citadel/webcit.

I believe that users with lower rights can't change it, at least when I tried, my users are "local users" (one Aide, and sometimes other for testing purposes).